# Accessing component $scope inside directive in 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using Angularjs components and ES6 to build an app that also uses d3js. I'm using an attribute directive for DOM manipulation. Since the component has the scope I'm trying to access it in the link function and inside use $watch. My doubt comes from the fact that the variables I'm trying to watch and access are inside $scope.$ctrl . What is the correct way to access them in this case?

**Template**

```
<div class="card">
    <svg network-svg>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
export const NetworkComponent = {

    template,
    controller: class NetworkComponent {

        constructor(CommService) {
            'ngInject'
            this.comm = CommService;
            this.physicalTree = new NodeTree('physical');
            this.virtualTree = new NodeTree('virtual');
            this.pVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Directive**
Current directive's code but returning undefined.

```
export const NetworkSvg = () => {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('virtualTree', function() {

            });

            $scope.$watch('physicalTree', function() {

            });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$ctrl` object is a property of scope. Simply use that in the watches:

```
export const NetworkSvg = () => {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) => {
            //$scope.$watch('virtualTree', function() {
            $scope.$watch('$ctrl.virtualTree', function(newValue) {
                 console.log(newValue);    
            });

            //$scope.$watch('physicalTree', function() {
            $scope.$watch('$ctrl.physicalTree', function(newValue) {
                 console.log(newValue);    
            });
         }
     }
}
```

Underneath the hood, the AngularJS framework uses `controller as $ctrl` when it instantiates a controller for a component. The `this` context of the controller is set to the `$ctrl` property of the component scope.

---

> So there's no harm in accessing it, in this case, with `$scope.$ctrl.physicalTree` ?

As a matter of robust design, it is better to avoid hardwiring model variable names into custom directives. Instead use an attribute to define the name:

```
export const NetworkSvg = () => {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
            //scope.$watch('virtualTree', function() {
            //scope.$watch('$ctrl.virtualTree', function() {
            scope.$watch(attrs.virtualTree, function(newValue) {
                console.log(newValue);    
            });

            //scope.$watch('physicalTree', function() {
            //scope.$watch('$ctrl.physicalTree', function() {
            scope.$watch(attrs.physicalTree, function(newValue) {
                console.log(newValue);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the attributes to define the wiring:

```
 <my-component virtual-tree="$ctrl.virtualTree"
               physical-tree="$ctrl.physicalTree" ></my-component>
```

This also makes for a more versitile directive where the wiring is clear.

---

> I'm having a hard time with this solution since, as far as I've tried and read, doing this through attributes the values passed are just string literals. How would I pass objects though?

Under the hood, `$watch` uses `scope.$eval` to evaluate the Angular Expression. Other code can use it as well:

For example:

```
<div my-event="$ctrl.handle($event)"></div>
```

JS:

```
link: (scope,elem,attrs) => {
    elem.on("someEvent", function(e) {
        scope.$eval(attrs.myEvent({$event: e});
        scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS scope.$eval API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)
- [AngularJS $parse Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: So there's no harm in accessing it, in this case, with $scope.$ctrl.physicalTree ?

Comment: Many thanks, that was exactly my doubt about it, seemed a little contrived. But I see attributes are the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, kinda rushed on accepting because it made very much sense. I'm having a hard time with this solution since, as far as I've tried and read, doing this through attributes the values passed are just string literals. How would I pass objects though?

Comment: Well my mistake, so far all your explaination was spot on. My mistake was that I was calling attrs.physical inside the listener function so obviously it was just a string literal. added the value parameter and it's working great. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one syntax error:
Can you replace directive code with this...and try

```
export const NetworkSvg = () => {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) => {
            $scope.$watch('virtualTree', () => {

            });

            $scope.$watch('physicalTree', () => {

            });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like it would be more clear if you pass attributes into your directive when it clearly depends on them. e.g.

```
<svg network-svg virtual-tree="virtualTree" physical-tree="physicalTree">
```

Then you'd be able to access these values within the `$attrs` property of the link function, as well as the scope on the controller.

Comment: Might be a dumb question but would that be compatible with the directive being used as an attribute?

Comment: No such thing as a dumb question when you're learning! ;) Yes it's perfectly compatible. You can pass attributes in this way regardless of whether the directive is defined using an element name, attribute or even class name.